# Mvc3 web app routing directly on index.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have created and host nvc3 web app 
now problem is when I open my `www.abc.com`
it is opening index.cshtml i.e home page of mvc web app

but I dont want that to be open when I open `www.abc.com`
I have one static page called `index.htm` should be open first

in mvc3 Global.asax code:

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

How can I render to `http://www.abc.com/mypage.html` ?
what should I please help.

Comment: ashuthinks - i don't think your idea of a static page as the landing page is a great idea. here's why. all your links in that page will be hardcoded which means that any changes to the domain name will have to be very carefully thought out (over and above any mvc routing concerns). i think an additional descritption of why you need the static page may help in providing an alternative solution

Comment: hi jim it is only for temporary time as i want to show site under construction page.

Comment: ahh -that makes a big difference. so are you saying that this will be the only page that's shown during this phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ashuthinks,

Based on your revised comments for the question. If you just want to show the 'Under contruction' type page with no links, then you can modify the `web.config` and add an `app_offline.htm` file. here's what those changes would look like:

web.config (bare bones):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

app_offline.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Your site title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <span>Your Company name</span>
    <h1>Sorry, server maintenance in progress </h1> 
    <h2>Please contact <a href="mailto:mycontact@mycompany.com">John Doe</a> on 000 123 456789 for further information</h2>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when you need to put the site live, simply rename the above files to `web.config_offline` and `app_offline.htm_offline` and bring your 'normal' web.config into play. There are of course many ways to skin this cat but this has worked well with previous projects that I've worked on.

see:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx

for further details.