# How do I redirect page in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have created and host MVC3 web app and now problem is that when I open my

**www.abc.com**

it is opening index.cshtml i.e home page of mvc web app

but I dont want that to be open when I open

**www.abc.com**

I have one static page called

index.htm

should be open first

in mvc3 Global.asax code:

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

How can I render to

```
http://www.abc.com/mypage.html
```

Comment: user911275 - isn't this an exact copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275523/mvc3-web-app-routing-directly-on-index-cshtml/9276267#9276267 ?? if so, give that solution a try

Comment: yes me too working on same issue but want to render using global.asax thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of the page to 'default.htm'. If that doesn't work, add another IgnoreRoute to that page in the RegisterRoutes(...) function.

Comment: after adding IgnoreRoute what exactly i need to write or change?

Answer (score 0):

> I have [blogged about](http://dheemhi.blogspot.in/2010/12/url-routing-aspnet-mvc.html) this

Add a new WebForm as a Default.aspx in Root directory ,

set it as Start up page

and on Page Load redirect it to your default URL. - Home\Index or any other Page.

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Home");
    }
}
```

Comment: swapneel - looks like asp.net webforms rather than mvc unfortunately, tho perhaps both can mix and match, never tried it this way before :)

Comment: Just a one Webform in MVC project which we are using to redirect to required page in App. There may be better solutions. i am not aware of it

Comment: @jim yes they can mix and match. but will not suggest to  mix them unless it is required.

Comment: i'm trying to render using global.asax but failed :(

Comment: u tried above solution? I think using Global aspx will not work because in IIS has settings has list to render index,aspx,index.asp,default.aspx,default.asp as a start up page. So for each user request IIS will try to render these pages